# How to wrap thumbnail image inside text in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know I have to ask in Wordpress forum.
But I am sort of crazy to `stackoverflow`, I ask here first.
I am developing Wordpress theme from scratch. Inside my blog post, I'd like to wrap the thumbnail image inside the text.
The code I used is

```
    <div class="row">

        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small'); ?></div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
           </div>

        <?php else: ?>      
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
```

Now is the content and thumbnail image are side by side.
I like to wrap the image inside text.
The image is [image: attached].

Comment: this is about HTML/CSS not WordPress itselfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrapping the thumbnail and the content in two different columns, that is  why they appear side by side. Change your code to this:

```
<div class="row">

        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small'); ?></div>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
           </div>

        <?php else: ?>      
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
```

Then float the thumbnail div to the left or right with css.

```
.thumbnail {
 float:left;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, that is what I want. Thanks